# 'Checkbox change' results in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

My requirement is to check/uncheck all other checkboxes on a checkbox change event
But results in infinite loop.

```js
$(".chk").change(function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var id = $this.attr('id');
  var chkOtherCheckboxes = 'on';
  if ($this.is(':checked')) {
    chkOtherCheckboxes = 'off';
  }
  $('input:checkbox:not("#' + id + '")').bootstrapToggle(chkOtherCheckboxes);
});
```

Comment: Because it gets _Toggled_ in the function which calls the `change` function again. It is more like recursion.

Comment: @NikhilWagh it's not a recursion as recursion has to have a stop condition

Comment: please share all your relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `bootstrapToggle` and change input, then enable it again.

```
$(".chk").change(function(event) {
  var id = this.id;
  var status = !this.checked;
  $('input:checkbox:not("#' + id + '")').each(function(){
    $(this).bootstrapToggle('destroy');
    $(this).prop('checked', status);
    $(this).bootstrapToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: prop('checked') is not working here. 
bootstrapToggle is the only thing i get to work the switch.

Comment: @Devi How about when you try with `bootstrapToggle('disable')` and enable?

Comment: using `bootstrapToggle('disable')` results in checkbox disable

Comment: @devi, sorry I was meant to do `destroy` instead of `disable`.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the same checkbox again `.chk` when user clicks on checkbox.

```
User click checkbox --> triggers change function -->
--> changes status of checkboxes( including itself) -->
--> again triggers change function
```

//infinite loop

Make sure you don't trigger change for the current checkbox.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank u for the suggestion. But my requirement is - checking any checkbox should result in unchecking all other checkboxes.

Comment: I got your requirement. I was just letting you know that you're triggering an event on the same checkbox again, which is not the correct way to do it :).
Above answer might solve your problem, but not the best way to solve this.